# How to identify the publisher of a message, in a multi-publisher to the same topic scenario?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Is there any way to know which Publisher published a particular message in ASB premium in scenario where multiple publishers are publishing to the same topic.

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus-reference#runtime-audit-logs), I see that it might be possible to get IP Address of client application (Publisher) only for aggregated diagnostic information for various data plane access operations (such as send or receive messages) in Premium Service Bus

Comment: Worth adding the link to the issue you've raised: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/680